# CUDA profiling information on part of a code

Tags: cuda

I want to profiling on a part of the code. For example, I need one million records from one million different execution. What tools or methods can I use?

Comment: Please use google the next time: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear. I want to make a million times the profiling of a code and save different outputs. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you read the link in my comment above? `nvprof` is also a command line tool ... you may programm a script to execute it how many times you want?